# Sum element by element multiple lists of different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to sum over multiple lists, index by index, to get one final list? Knowing that these lists might not have the same length? For example, with these

```
[2,4,0,0], [0,0,2], [0,4]
```

I would like to have

```
[2,8,2,0]
```

as a result.

I haven't found any result so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with the `fillvalue` argument set to `0`. If you use this in a list comprehension, you can unpack and zip the inner lists and add them in an element-wise fashion.

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [sum(i) for i in zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=0)]
[2, 8, 2, 0]
```